# loop instead of if statements for calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, if-statement, input

I’m trying to figure out how I can get this code shorten into a loop or so.

Basically I have two input fields that need to be filled:

```
<input type="number" id="people" name="people" value="0"> 
<input type="text"  id="upprice" name="upprice" value="0">
```

This is the current situation how I solved it:

```
var upPrice = 0,
    people  = 0;

$('#people').on('change', function() {
    countValue = this.value;

    if (countValue >= 10) {
        upPrice = 1000;
    } 

    if (countValue >= 20) {
        upPrice = 2000;
    } 

    if (countValue >= 30) {
        upPrice = 2500;
    } 

    if (countValue >= 40) {
        upPrice = 3000;
    } 

    $('#upprice').attr('value', upPrice);
});
```

Technically it’s a calculation that fires an upcharge every 10th step. First to steps the upcharge has a value of 1000, the next two 500 and so on…and it goes up to 250.

I guess the most rational method to do this would be a loop, right? Unfortunately I’m not able to get the loop right, can anyone help me out or gimme an advice how to solve this properly?

Comment: You need an equation, not a loop.

Comment: `the next two 500 and so on` so it's 1000,2000,2500,3000 ... what's the next increment? "and so on" doesn't really help with the next step, let alone the next 21 steps (I assume the 250 is the maximum countValue you check against)

Comment: thanks for the quick response! the snippet above was for visualization first. the steps are: countValue 0-50, upprice = 0 / countValue 50-100, upprice = 1000 (every 10th step) / countValue 100-150, upprice = 500 (each 10th step), countValue 150-250, upprice = 300 (each 10th step)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a table -

```
var tbl = [0, 1000, 2000, 2500, 3000, and so on];
```

then

```
upPrice = tbl[Math.min(Math.floor(countValue / 10), 25)];
```

as per comments, to "start" the upPrice after countValue > 50

```
upPrice = tbl[Math.max(Math.min(Math.floor((countValue - 50) / 10), 25), 0)];
```

Comment: this one does the calculation pretty well. what if I want to start calculating every 10th step after the value of #people has reached 50? Tried an if-statement, but it directly executes 5000 instead of starting at 0 from there.

Comment: no idea what #people has to do with the question ... oh, wait, I see now ... did you try `upPrice = tbl[Math.min(Math.floor((countValue - 50) / 10), 25)];`

Comment: yessir, just tried it. upprice is NaN until the first 10 is reached, then it executes every single step.

Comment: oops, yeah, need to do `upPrice = tbl[Math.max(Math.min(Math.floor((countValue - 50) / 10), 25), 0)];` to properly limit the indices to 0...25